# Access Token through Azure Active Directory for Graph API ends in Property Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, postman, outlook-api

I'm trying to call the **Graph API**: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail.
I run the query successfully with the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), where I gave my user the Mail.Send permission. And if I use the Access Token from the Graph Explorer in **Postman** it works too.

But if I use my own Access Token which I create from calling the Azure Active Directory App in ends in this error:

```
  {
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBodyRead",
        "message": "The property 'subject' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type. REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview. You can find more information about the preview REST APIs at https://dev.outlook.com/.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-12-23T12:47:23",
            "request-id": "cbb00b85-295b-45e2-abc7-f064ec52f994",
            "client-request-id": "cbb00b85-295b-45e2-abc7-f064ec52f994"
        }
    }
```

The body in the message is the same, I just changed the Access Token from the Graph Explorer to the one I created. The Access Token is created through a **POST Request** to:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb09-9f3-476-9bf-4f126479986
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I checked both Tokens with https://jwt.io/ if they vary in some way. The only thing which was odd was the parameter "aud" for Audience. The value in my Token was different than the one from the Graph Explorer, but I don't know if I can change that.

The Azure Active Directory App does have the necessary permissions, also with Admin consens.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JbRk.png)

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given Delegated permissions to the application which allow your app to call an API on behalf of a user.
But you authenticate using only application credentials where no user is involved.
In that case only Application permissions apply.

You either need to grant the "Send mail as any user" Application permission (and use /users/user-id instead of /me), or you need to change how you authenticate such that it involves a user at some point of the process.

Comment: I tried invoking an HTTP request as the user with the corrected Url but unfortunately it ends in the same error as previously. I still run into the issue of the property error.

Comment: Since you mention "aud" being different, that could be related to your issue. What is the aud value you get?

Comment: The Audience "aud" from the Graph Explorer is "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", which works. But the Audience I get in return from my http request is "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com".

Comment: Those should both be valid. The first is the client ID for MS Graph and the second is the app ID URI. What do you have in "scp" / "roles" claims?

Comment: "scp": "Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite.Shared Mail.Send Mail.Send.Shared openid profile Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All User.Read email" for both the token from the graph explorer and the one I get from the http request. That's what confuses me, because both Token differ that much.

Comment: Okay so since you have scopes, it means it is using delegated permissions and calling MS Graph API on behalf of the user. Is it that user's mail that you are trying to send it from?

Comment: Yes, from the same user.

Comment: any new idea how I can tackle this problem?